# jQuery Apply style to only first element

Tags: jquery, each

In the following code, I am trying to get the last if statement to only minus the `margin-top` from the FIRST `div.wigDiv` `parent`. Everything is working, except that its applying the negative margin to ALL `div.wigDiv` parents. Any ideas?

```
$('.wigCont').each(function() {

   //some other code here

   if ($('div.wigDiv', this).hasClass('noMargin')) {
      if (wigCount == 1) {
         var width = $('div.wigDiv', this).width();
         $('div.wigDiv', this).css({'margin-left':'-18px', 'width': width+36});

         if ($('div.wigDiv', this).parent().first()) {
            $('div.wigDiv', this).parent().css('margin-top','-20px');
         }
      }
   }
}
```

Comment: An element can only have one parent, something many answers neglect to take into account (except for Alessandro's), so doing `.first()` on `.parent()` does nothing. I think you may mean the parent of the first `div.wigDiv` contained in the current `.wigCont` (`this` inside the `each`), or possibly the parent of the `div.wigDiv` in the first `.wigCont` (i.e., first iteration of the `each`. It's not entirely clear. Posting the HTML would help clear up the confusion, if you can simplify it.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Try this code:

```
$('.wigCont').each(function() {

   //some other code here

   if ($('div.wigDiv', this).hasClass('noMargin')) {
      if (wigCount == 1) {
         var width = $('div.wigDiv', this).width();
         $('div.wigDiv', this).css({'margin-left':'-18px', 'width': width+36});

         if ($('div.wigDiv', this).parent().is(':first-child')) {
            $('div.wigDiv', this).parent().css('margin-top','-20px');
         }
      }
   }
}
```

Answer (score 1):

You just need to use `.first` as you have in that `if` condition. Also You don't need that if condition as it would apply only if it finds the matching elements.

```
$('div.wigDiv', this).parent().first().css('margin-top','-20px');
```

**Full Code:**

```
$('.wigCont').each(function() {

   if ($('div.wigDiv', this).hasClass('noMargin')) {
      if (wigCount == 1) {
         var width = $('div.wigDiv', this).width();
         $('div.wigDiv', this).css({'margin-left':'-18px', 'width': width+36});

         //below is the modified code
         $('div.wigDiv', this).parent().first().css('margin-top','-20px');
      }
   }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

You're doing

```
$('div.wigDiv', this).parent().css('margin-top','-20px');
```

Need to do `parent().first().css` :)

Answer (score 0):

Quick note before answer: your last if statement will always be true because `$('div.wigDiv', this).parent().first()` returns an object.

To filter to only the first selected element, use `.first()`

```
$('div.wigDiv', this).parent().first().css('margin-top','-20px');
```